# Printing the longest sequence of alternating negative and positive numbers (including 0)

Tags: python

I have the following input `a = [1, -2, 3, 5, 0, -3, 4, -6, 2]` and I must display the longest sequence that alternates between negative and positive value (0 being positive)

So the program would return 0 -3 4 -6 2 since it is the longest sequence of this type

This it what i have so far but it's my second Py program and I totally got stuck:

```
n = int(input())

numbers = []
counter = 0

nr = input().split(' ')

for i in range(0,len(nr)):
  if nr[i] * nr[i+1] < 0:
    counter += 1
  else:
    counter = 0
  print(counter)
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question? "I got stuck" is not a good problem description.

Comment: @mkrieger1 there is however a pretty clear problem statement above

Comment: Can you describe in your own words what you'd like the python algorithm to do?

Comment: Check out [Longest alternating positive and negative subarray](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-alternating-positive-negative-subarray-starting-every-index/) for an approach to this problem.

Comment: I did. With example of input and output

Comment: But you didn't describe what the problem with your code is. Please explain how you are running it, what exactly you provide as input, and what you get as result instead of what you had expected. Is there an error message? If so, please include it with the complete stack trace in the question.

Comment: Your test `nr[i] * nr[i+1] < 0` is flawed.  From your example, you want to consider `0` a positive number, but `0 * -3` (==0) is not less than zero, so you are treating `0` and `-3` as being a pair of numbers with the same sign (so not part of a potential answer).  Try `(nr[i] < 0) != (nr[i+1] < 0)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with only one loop but unfortunately 3 if statements:

```
nr = [1, -2, 3, 5, 0, -3, 4, -6, 2] # input list
nr2 = nr.copy() # dummy list to replace 0 by 1 as they are considered positive

counter = 0 # counter for length of alternating sequence in the for loop
max_counter = 0 # max counter seen so far
max_index = 0 # index of the max counter in the list

# iteration over the dummy list starting at nr2[1] as nr2[0] is considered counter = 0
for i in range(1, len(nr2)):
    if nr2[i] == 0: 
        nr2[i] = 1
    if nr2[i-1] * nr2[i] < 0:
        counter += 1
        if counter > max_counter:
            max_counter = counter
            max_index = i
    else:
        counter = 0
# print out the longest sequence of the input list nr    
print(nr[max_index-max_counter:max_index+1])
```

Please note that I have implemented the comparison of list elements in a backward fashion and not forward looking like you did.

Test run:

```
IN: nr = [1, -2, 3, 5, 0, -3, 4, -6, 2]
OUT: [0, -3, 4, -6, 2]

IN: nr = [1, -2, 3, -5, 0, -3, 4, -6, 2]
OUT: [1, -2, 3, -5, 0, -3, 4, -6, 2]

IN: nr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 3, 4, 6, 2]
OUT: [1]
```

Answer (score -1):

you could use a recursive function to determine the longest sequence, here's a quick and dirty proposed solution:

```py
a = [1, -2, 3, 5, 0, -3, 4, -6, 2]
def longest_alternating_sequence(result, index, items, sign):
    if index > len(items) - 1:
        return (index, result)

    if items[index] >= 0 and sign == '-':
        result.append(items[index])
        result.append(longest_alternating_sequence(result, index + 1, items, '+')[1].pop())
    elif items[index] < 0 and sign == '+':
        result.append(items[index])
        result.append(longest_alternating_sequence(result, index + 1, items, '-')[1].pop())

    return (index, result)

sequences = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    (index, result) = longest_alternating_sequence([], i, a, ('+', '-')[int(a[i] >= 0)])
    sequences.append((index, result))

max_seq = (0,[])
for (index, seq) in sequences:
    if len(seq) > len(max_seq[1]):
        max_seq = (index, seq)

print('max sequence is {}, starting at index {}'.format(max_seq[1], max_seq[0]))
```

this would print:

```
max sequence is [0, -3, 4, -6, 2], starting at index 4
```