# Finding the longest negative/positive sequence in a list and displaying it

Tags: python

From a list that looks like this `a = [1,-3,0,-1,0,4,4,-1,3,-1,7]` I have to detect and display the longest negative-positive sequence (where 0 is seen as positive).

So the intermediary list should look something like `int = [[1,-3,0,-1],[4,-1,3,-1,7]]` and the displayed list should be the longest from int which is `longest = [4,-1,3,-1,7]`

I have written this code that outputs this: `int = [-1, 0, -3, 4, -1, 5, ' ', ' ', -6, 0, -1]`

How can I create more separate lists from the `int` list above (ideally splitting at ' ')?

Code:

```
lista = input().split()
lista = list(map(int,lista))
lista2 = []

for i in range(0,len(lista)-1):

    if lista[i]<0 and lista[i+1]>=0 or lista[i]>=0 and lista[i+1]<0:
        if lista[i] in lista2:
            lista2.append(lista[i+1])
        else:
            lista2.append(lista[i])
            lista2.append(lista[i+1])
    else:
       lista2.append(' ')
```

Where `list2` is the `int` list from my example

Comment: Different approach but here is someone with the very same task to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58726793/12268505

Comment: Why `int = [[1,-3,0,-1],[4,-1,3,-1,7]]` and not `int = [[1,-3,0,-1,0],[4,-1,3,-1,7]]`? Also, you shouldn't use `int` as a variable name, as this is the name of the builtin integer class/constructor/function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create intermediary lists. You can check its lengthes inside the loop:

```
longest, temp = [], []
pos_sign = True
for num in a:
    if ((num >= 0) == pos_sign) or len(temp) == 0:
        temp.append(num)
        if len(temp) == 0:
            pos_sign = (num >= 0)
        else:
            pos_sign = not pos_sign
    else:
        if len(temp) > len(longest):
            longest = temp
        temp = []
        pos_sign = (num >= 0)
if len(temp) > len(longest):
    longest = temp
#OUTPUT [1, -3, 0, -1, 0] which is the right output for the list in the question
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
a = [1,-3,0,-1,0,4,4,-1,3,-1,7]

 final_list = []
 working_list = [a.pop(0)]

for i in a:
    polarity = working_list[-1] >= 0
    if (i >= 0) == polarity:
        working_list = [i]
    else:
        working_list.append(i)
    if len(working_list) > len(final_list):
        final_list = working_list
```

print(final_list)

```
    [1, -3, 0, -1, 0]
```

You call yours an intermediary list, I call mine a working list. Either way, it's just a memory store to hold your latest candidate for biggest sequence. I'm using 2 global vars as memory here.

- `final_list` keeps track of the biggest list found so far
- `working_list` is the current sequence

Every loop looks at the last value in the working list to work out whether or not the sequence is continuing. If it does and the list is bigger than the current final list - the final list is updated with the current working list. If not - we start a new working list.

If your output definitely needs to be the last sequence as per your question, then change `if len(working_list) > len(final_list):` to `if len(working_list) >= len(final_list):` and you'll get the desired result.